# custom x-axis ticks in chart js

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm creating a graph like this.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6vku.png

I have data for each minute. The thing I want to show is my axis like this chart as 10 am, 12 pm, 2 pm, 4 pm. It should have fixed ticks as shown in this graph and if I have stock price till 2 pm then it should show the graph line till 2 pm but the x-axis should be fixed rest part of the graph would be empty.

What I tried-

```
 ticks: {
     
        callback: function(val, index,values) {
            let x = (dataSet.labels[index])
            if(x==='09:00:00'|| x==='10:00:00'||x==='12:00:00'||x==='02:00:00'||x==='04:00:00'){
                return dataSet.labels[index] 
            }
        },
```

This is working fine I`m getting data as I want but If I don't have data till 10 am it fills the complete graph and doesn't show the next ticks 12 pm, 2 pm, 4 pm.